# Substitution of main function (y) into differential equation

Tags: calculus, substitution, differential

I have a problem understanding how these substitutions are possible in examples (2) & (3), clearly this is not the main function as the place of the (A) & (B) parameters are switched in example (2), so how is this possible?

Same in the example (3), the initial power of the exp function is different.

Any clarification would be appreciated, thank you!

images here:

https://ibb.co/YdKKHVk
https://ibb.co/y0Sr3F6

Comment: use mathjax instead of images

Comment: I'll definitely learn that and do it the next time

Comment: so it's assumed here the A=B ?

Comment: i get it, but aren't you making an assumption here? what if A != B ?
can you still do that?

Comment: I see... it goes back to the original y function. Thanks!
what about the example 3 case? those two are variables

Comment: both links are next to each other, so the second one, here: https://ibb.co/y0Sr3F6

Comment: no i dont think so, but how can you go from [exp(y)=xy] to [exp(x)=xy]? in which case?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Moo! I really appreciate that :)